# What can I be allowed to do as a engineering/ maintenance intern at a european airline?

Tags: easa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

I am just about to (*hopefully*) embark on a short internship at the maintenance department of a medium-sized european airline (i.e. under EASA framework).

While the internship has been pushed towards being practical, one thing that bothers me is that I am absolutely clueless what I could be allowed to do (and I'd like to know so I could negotiate to get the most of the time with the carrier).

**For instance:**

- Would I be allowed to handle anything flight-wise with supervision? Could I be allowed to interact with the aircraft or only watch and observe?
- Would I be allowed to even loosen a bolt on a wheel, or do you legally need maintenance certification for that?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to specify what sort of engineering (i.e. are you a mechanical engineer, electrical, software, aerospace, etc.?)

Comment: @reirab aerospace engineer; pretty inexperienced (BSc student).

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity for you, and sounds like a great question to ask those who are about to hire you for the position. `I'd like to help you the most while learning the most for me, what will I be allowed to do and what will I be expected to do?` seems like a good interview question.

Comment: Maybe @Thunderstrike could follow up with a description of the kinds of task she was allowed to perform?

Answer (score 2):

In europe the MRO are regulated by Part 145, this part precise that you have to be  Certifying staff (owner of part 66) to work on aircraft. 
For all other people you can't even loose a bolt except if you are under supervision of qualified Certifying staff.

For engineering work (without work on aircraft) you only need to have a sufficient degree (under company appreciation except for special works like airworthiness where this in precised in concerned regulation (Part M for example)).

Comment: So sounds like he can do anything if under supervision of certified mechanic?

Comment: And what is meant by "supervised?" Does that mean they have to be standing there watching you turn the bolt?

Comment: You can do the work but in theory a certified mechanic must supervise you to ensure that you doing well the job. The main problem is that a certified mechanics must take the responsibility of your work.